# Share discussion post accross community sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, discussion-board

I am facing this requirement with the `community sites` that users from 2 different community sites want to access the post posted in one's community site.

Let me simplify this, consider there is `CommunitySite1 & CommunitySite2` and i am the owner of `CommunitySite1` and posted a post(in `Discussion List`) in my `CommunitySite1`, now I want to give permission to a `User` in `CommunitySite2` to view & reply my post in `CommunitySite1`.

Is there anyway to implement this and Share my post with member in other `CommunitySite`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to ---> `Site Setting` ---> `In Users and Permissions` ---> `click People and groups` ---> In `members` group add that user .

Comment: I don't want to add user permanently to my Community I just want him to access only that particular discussion and nothing else from my CommunitySite

Comment: For this you have to give atleast Read Permissions to the site and contribute permissions to that discussion list...is this ok?